# How to use schedule recieving value from list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, schedule

I m expecting to receive values from a list to use on schedule

```
import schedule
import time


times_input = []


times_input = [item for item in input("Times (hh:mm) script will work. Space to add a new time (Eg: 10:30 15:59 23:12):\n:> ").split()]
print(times_input)

def job():
    print("I'm working..." + n)
    
    global times_input
for n in times_input:
    #print(n)
    schedule.every().day.at(n).do(job)
    #print(n)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

return:

```
Times (hh:mm) script will work. Space to add a new time (Eg: 10:30 15:59 23:12):
:> 03:25 03:26
['03:25', '03:26']
I'm working...03:26
I'm working...03:26
```

But its not working properly, as you can see the script worked 2 times but printed same "times". Any idea where is my error?

Comment: You need to explain what is not working and what you expect to happen.  It's also a good idea to hard-code input to make your program non-interactive.  This makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely because you are using global variables, while you should NOT.
If you need something inside a function (like `n`) parameter, then you should

- pass it as an argument to that function
- or get it somewhere

Your script prints twice the same thing, because during both time, the last known value of `n` was 03:26. But what you intended to do, is to obtain a new time value

```
import datetime

def job():
    print("blabla " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
```